# Error with a authentication script. Password not recognize

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a restricted area but I have some problems with password authentication. The system doesn't recognize the password stored into database

step by step. **New user:**

```
$userName = $_POST['txtUserName'];
$password = $_POST['txtPassword'];
  $sql   = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (user_name, user_password, user_regdate)
              VALUES ('$userName', PASSWORD('$password'), NOW())";
```

This works. I have a new user stored into database

Database: MySQL V5.6

```
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`user_password` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

 ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

So I try **to login** (from login form):

```
// if we found an error save the error message in this variable
$errorMessage = '';

$userName = $_POST['txtUserName'];
$password = $_POST['txtPassword'];

// first, make sure the username & password are not empty
if ($userName == '') {
    $errorMessage = 'You must enter your User Name';
} else if ($password == '') {
    $errorMessage = 'You must enter your password';
} else {
    // check the database and see if the username and password combo do match
    $sql = "SELECT user_id
            FROM tbl_user 
                WHERE user_name = '$userName' AND user_password = PASSWORD('$password')";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);
if (dbNumRows($result) == 1) {
        $row = dbFetchAssoc($result);
        $_SESSION['plaincart_user_id'] = $row['user_id'];

        // log the time when the user last login
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_user 
                SET user_last_login = NOW() 
                    WHERE user_id = '{$row['user_id']}'";
        dbQuery($sql);

        // now that the user is verified we move on to the next page
        // if the user had been in the admin pages before we move to
        // the last page visited
        if (isset($_SESSION['login_return_url'])) {
            header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['login_return_url']);
            exit;
        } else {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        $errorMessage = 'Username or password wrong';
    }       

     }

     return $errorMessage;
       }
```

It seems that doesn't recognize the password function (), because if I write manually in the database password fiels a value not encrypted, it works...

Comment: Make sure your column length for the password is long enough. Also check to see if your form's elements all contain name attributes and that the session has indeed been started; seeing you're using sessions. Check for errors on all sides PHP/SQL.

Comment: From mysql documentation: `The Password column must be wide enough to hold long hashes (41 bytes).`

Comment: *"It seems that doesn't recognize the password function ()"* - It's contradicting with what you said *"This works. I have a new user stored into database"*. --- *"if I write manually in the database password fiels a value not encrypted, it works."* Check your form element names. **Better yet, post your HTML form.** Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: OMG! yes it was a column length problems....so stupid! thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're using MySQL's PASSWORD function for a use it's not intended for. Aside from being a horrible idea from a security standpoint (plaintext passwords can end up in the logs), it also means that MySQL will silently truncate the password if the password field isn't long enough for it.  This will results in password hashes that can never match.

You need to look into password hashing to make your passwords more secure and less prone to truncation errors (DO NOT USE MD5 OR SHA-1 FOR THIS! Even SHA-256 is dubious).  You also need to determine how long a hash string will be for the method you've chosen and make sure the password field is big enough to take it.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php